# Maximum TCP client connection number on Windows 7 Pro for a C# TCP server software

Tags: c#, windows-7, connection, tcpserver

i am running a TCP server on my machine. My operating sytem is Windows 7 Professional. I tested my server with a TCP connection test software and i think my computer does not allow more than 300-400 connections. I tested my software for 1000 TCP clients and everytime my software (or computer i don't know) does not accept more than 300-400 connections.

What is the maximum number of connections for a PC (not a server PC) practically not theoretically. I am developing software on a Windows 7 PC but i will use the software on a Windows Server so i want to know if the problem is my operating system or my software.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to the number of ports that can be opened. The defaults are pretty less. 
Check [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cbi/v10r1m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.c8pp_inst.10.1.1.doc/t_orclsbssktsprts.html) link to get steps on increasing them on windows

The max I believe is 65534

Comment: I don't think so because my server only listens port 1234. I think my test software (another computer in network) can open enough ports for testing server.

Comment: @petre - server listens on one port only, however when ever a connection is accepted a new port is used to carry on that communication. If your clients are long running ones which do not close the connection soon enough then the number of ports used goes up.

Answer (score 2):

I remember that there is a setting to limit the number of connections to a TCP port to avoid DoS attacks (Denial Of Service).

This is a setting that can be deactivated, maybe this is the limit you're reaching.

Look [here](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-tcpip-max-limit.html)